# Plugin for SonarQube, how to get currently-logged-in user id on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, sonarqube

I'm developing a plugin for SonarQube that adds (among other things) a new page where a user can upload a profile picture.  To accomplish this, I need to get the id of the currently logged in User.  First, I tried this:

```
<p>The Current User Id = <%=@User.id-%></p>
```

The result:

> The Current User Id = 4

There are only two users in my instance of Sonar with IDs of 1 and 2, so I knew this couldn't be correct.  So I tried this:

```
<p>The Current User Id = <%=@User.id-%></p>
<p>The Current Project Id = <%=@User.id-%></p>
```

The result:

> The Current User Id = 4
>   The Current Project Id = 4

I then noticed that the Windows CMD window had this text in it after I viewed the page:

> warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id

So I tried this:

```
<p>The Current User Id = <%=@User.user_id-%></p>
```

The result was this:
[image]

So, how do I get the id of the currently logged in User on a page in my plugin?

Comment: what is the value of `@User in the controller action, also I think it's best not to use @User with a capital U but to a use a lowercase @user. Are you using a gem for authentication like Devise or have you done it from scratch?

Comment: The long and short of it is, I haven't done it -- the controller action for finding the currently logged in user (if there is one -- and there's got to be) is in the SonarQube application itself.  I've tried to find it in SonarQube's source code, but to no avail.  Also, I just tried making `@User` `@user` instead and tried the combinations again, but there was no difference.
I don't know if this helps, but `@Project` actually works when I'm coding a new widget, but not when I'm coding a new page.

Comment: How are you interacting with SonarQube? Through a gem? From what I've [read](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Started) you need to be coding the plugin in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user is logged in, you have acccess to a "current_user" variable.

See for instance the ["account" ERB template](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar/blob/master/sonar-server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/app/views/account/index.html.erb) that display info about the current user in SonarQube.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  In the future I'll remember to not just look at SonarQube's source code, but also in the Sonar-Server/WEB-INF directory to find example source code.  Thank you!